# Shiro SessionDAO class loading issue in shared library

Tags: java, deserialization, classnotfoundexception, shiro

I am getting a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.pricing.shared.MyClass` and I don't understand why given that the class is on the classpath.

Here is the config I'm using:
I have 2 war files in the same Tomcat 7 instance:

1. `ROOT.war` pointing to www.example.com/
2. `app.war`pointing to www.example.com/app/*

Both files contain 2 shared libraries:

1. `commons.jar`
2. `pricing.jar`

The `commons.jar` lib contains the `SessionDAO` class which extends Shiro's `AbstractSessionDAO`. My SessionDAO class is a basic implementation which saves the Shiro Session in a MySQL table (VARCHAR id, BLOB Session object).

Now when I try to access a URL of the `app.war` module I get the following exception while de-serializing the Session from the DB:

```
org.apache.shiro.session.SessionException: Class not found exception while reading Session from input stream!
com.example.dao.SessionDAO.deserialize(SessionDAO.java:97)
... (omitted)

Root cause:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.pricing.shared.MyClass 
java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
```

The faulty deserialize method is as follow:

```
private static Session deserialize(ResultSet resultSet, String col){
    ByteArrayInputStream bais=null;
    ObjectInputStream ins=null;
    Session res=null;
    try{
        byte[] barray=resultSet.getBytes(col);
        if(barray!=null){
            bais=new ByteArrayInputStream(barray);
            ins=new ObjectInputStream(bais);
            res=(Session)ins.readObject();
        }
    }catch(IOException e){
        throw new SessionException("IO exception while reading Session from input stream!",e);
    }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
        throw new SessionException("Class not found exception while reading Session from input stream!",e);//the one causing the issue
    }catch(SQLException e){
        throw new SessionException("SQL exception while reading Session from input stream!",e);
    }finally{
        try{
            ins.close();
        }catch(NullPointerException|IOException e){}
        try{
            bais.close();
        }catch(NullPointerException|IOException e){}
    }
    return res;
}
```

Do you have any idea of how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Shiro's libs were in the Tomcat/lib folder whereas the 2 jars were in the WEB-INF/lib folder. 
Moving Shiro's libs in WEB-INF/lib fixed the issue.